# Firebase Cloud Messaging Statistics API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm using an application server to send messages by Firebase Cloud Messaging.
Firebase console does not list such a message which sent by app server.
When I use Firebase console directly to send messages, it will display some analysis on its own messages.

Like this:
[image]

The questions is, how can I access message statistics when I'm using an app servers?

Comment: Are you looking for an API?

Comment: @AL Yes, I'm looking for such a thing preferably but a GUI console would be acceptable (in future).

Comment: Did you find a way to log also the `notification_open` data, for messages send via the API?

Comment: @LeonBraun Sorry It is long time passed from that time and I currently have not those codes to check it to help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of August 2018 (announced in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/in-app-messaging-crashlytics.html)), API send stats can be viewed in the "Reports" tab of the FCM console. By default it only shows `notification` type messages, so if you're only sending `data` messages with the API, be sure to choose the "Data" filter.

[image]

---

*Before August 2018:*

The Firebase Notifications charts only show analytics for messages that were sent using the Firebase Notifications panel.

There is currently no public API to send Notifications to audiences. The web interface in the console is the only way to send them.

There is currently no API to feed your own FCM messages into the Firebase Notifications analytics panels.

Comment: In addition, if you also have a Play Dev Console account and if your app is in at least Alpha Testing, you can make use of the [Diagnostics and Statistics page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en). However, I don't think there is also an API available for it.