# GCM / FCM / Mozilla (Web Push Service) usage statics

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, mozilla, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use the HTTP Web API to send Downstream messages over GCM (recently switch to FCM) as well as Mozilla push.

GCM and FCM got a push authorization key and I assume that Google can clearly identify me as the message sender.

FCM URL (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

The Mozilla push service seems to be anonymous since it does not require any authorization key.

Mozilla (https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/)

My implementation does work and push messages are send to Chrome, Firefox and Android.

However, I cannot find any usage Statistics. I looked into the Firebase console as well the Google cloud console. All counters remains zero.

Can I or should I be able to see the usage statics for the Google push service ? Is their something similar Mozilla ?

Thanks for looking into this.

Regards
Stefan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase notification records/log API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340076/firebase-notification-records-log-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently only one way to find the statistics/statuses of the messages sent through <s>GCM/</s>FCM.

From the *Cloud Messaging* section in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/reporting):

[image]

It would seem that the Impressions and Opens are still only available for messages sent using the console. But Sends for sure now counts the messages sent using the FCM API.

Reference: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/in-app-messaging-crashlytics.html

---

<sub>I haven't tried Mozilla Push Service before so I'm unable to comment on that one.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. The Play Console > FCM Statistic which started to work after i associated the Sender ID was what i was looking for.