# Firebase cloud messaging message log

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Android app I receive messages sent using Firebase, the problem is **not all messages arrive** and sometimes messages arrival is very slow.

In my server side I track the messages I send to FCM and I always receive **success: 1** response from FCM, still there are messages I do not receive in my Android app.

I thought an FCM messages log would be a great help in cases like described above but I don't sure if this option exist.

Is there a way to browse Firebase Messages log ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase notification records/log API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340076/firebase-notification-records-log-api)

Comment: If you sent the message via the console, you could see some details from there as well, if you used the API and sending it with your server, you should keep track of the response logs. If it shows success, yet the message doesn't appear on the client, share the code you have for receiving the messages so we could help further.

Comment: @AL. I sent messages using the  FCM console. most of messages arrived in seconds... still there were a few messages with status Scheduled for long time...., minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you know that Firebase Cloud Messages can be delayed if the connected device is in doze mode and your app's standby bucket is not high enough to wake up the device? Therefore, even if FCM sends the message to your target device in time, there is still a chance that it will be delayed by the Android platform. Also, if the message is sent with high priority, you might have a chance to wake up the device from doze mode to be able to receive the message in time.

The following two docs will give you a more detailed explanation:

- https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby
- https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details

Besides, FCM provides three sets of tools to help you get insight into message delivery:

1. Firebase console message delivery reports (go to Firebase Console -> Messaging -> Reports)
2. Aggregated Android SDK delivery metrics from the Firebase Cloud Messaging Data API
3. Comprehensive data export to Google BigQuery

All these three tools can help you understand your message delivery, the following docs have a pretty good explanation about how to use them:

- https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-is-fcm-aggregated-delivery-data-d6d68396b83b
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#count-data-messages-sent