# Firebase Diagnostics on Play Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-console

I have a firebase project. I want to know the details diagnostics and statistics of every campaigns. We have panel for scheduling and sending notification to devices. Firebase deliver notifications to devices.

I want to know to which devices, the notifications are delivered, to which it is undelivered. I have read something about play console. I have followed the steps and linked my Firebase project with Google play console
but, still I am unable to see any stats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase notification records/log API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340076/firebase-notification-records-log-api)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [FCM Diagnostics tool](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) has been removed. From the links:

> **November 30, 2017: FCM diagnostics data removed**
>
> You can no longer access FCM diagnostics data in the Play Console.
>
> You can still use other [Firebase Cloud Messaging features](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).