# How can I see statistical result when i use Firebase FCM with http request

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I am using FCM to do Mobile Push Notification. When I use firebase Notification console to push Notification, i can see every Notification statistics, but when I use http api to push Notification, I can't see statistical table.
Is FCM have a way for me to get statistics such as mobile arrival rate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase notification records/log API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340076/firebase-notification-records-log-api)