# Track Firebase notification for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to see number of successfully sent and failed push notifications  in Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) ? I can see the messages sent using the Firebase console but I need to track the number of messages sent via the web app to the devices.

Google explains how to get access to statistics on android https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268. But is there a similar way for iOS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase notification records/log API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340076/firebase-notification-records-log-api)

Answer (score -1):

> In one word yes, You can do it.

Firebase API have a message_id as a response parameter. It's indicate notification is deliver or not.

```
message_id: String specifying a unique ID for each successfully processed message.
```

Please find below attached screenshots.

[image: Firebase API Response parameter]

[Please do refer this reference.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

**Update:**

> You can not track user activity for notification in iOS application. If you want to
>   implement above functionality then call any custom API and store required data into your
>   database. You can not get any history directly.

Comment: Thanks @iMHitesh for your reply. But My requirement is to log events for the notification. For example, when the user taps on the notification I want to log the event in my firebase portal. Is there any way for Custom events?

Comment: There is no any inbuilt functionality as per your requirement. Please refer update