# FCM: Access all sent push messages

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The goal I want to achieve for the app owner is to send FCM push notifications via web interface to the customers (already achieved) and to give the customers a view in my app, on which they can read all or at least the last 10 sent push messages. Is there any (REST) api in FCM which can be used to receive the sent push notifications and its content so I can display them in my Android fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no available API as of the moment to retrieve your GCM/FCM logs. However, there's been a recent improvement in the Firebase Notifications console where stats for messages sent using the FCM API is included in the Firebase Notification console stats. 
The more details can be found from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40341195/8809599) and the [blogpost](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/in-app-messaging-crashlytics.html).