# How to get Firebase notification status (opened or not) which is sent from PHP backend?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

When I send any notification from Firebase console, I can monitor my notification status (how many device received or how many opened it) from Firebase console.

Now I developed a PHP backend and using `curl` I can send notification to my users. I need to monitor ***How many devices are received my notification and how many devices opened it?*** for each notification.

Is it possible? Please let me know about best practice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the ***How many devices are received my notification*** part, I think you should make use of [Delivery Receipts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#ccs):

> **Delivery Receipt**: If the app server included `delivery_receipt_requested` in the downstream message, the XMPP connection server sends a delivery receipt when it receives confirmation that the device received the message.

For the ***how many devices opened it*** part, I think this should be a custom implementation on your client app. For example, if the user does click your notification and open a specific activity of your app, you should then [Send an Upstream message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream), specifying that the notification was opened.

Comment: That means there are no options to monitor these status from Firebase console. I have to handle it myself. Am I right?

Comment: @HasanAbdullah Yes. The notification statistics that are visible on the console are also the ones which were sent from the console. See FrankvanPuffelen's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40132973/4625829).